# Is it possible to use an Apple Watch to authorise sudo in Catalina?

Tags: terminal, catalina, apple-watch, sudo, authorization

MacOS Catalina let us do some higher privilege actions on our Mac by [authorising through a press on our Apple Watch button](https://ioshacker.com/how-to/unlock-mac-apps-with-apple-watch-macos-catalina).

Would it be possible to use that feature to authorise a `sudo` command in the Terminal?

Comment: Depends what do you mean by "*possible*".  You could change the `$SUDO_ASKPASS` environment variable to define a helper program (that you wrote) to do the validation.  This program would then pass the password to [tgetpass.c](https://opensource.apple.com/source/sudo/sudo-86.50.1/sudo/src/tgetpass.c.auto.html).  See this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608293/how-to-setup-a-sudo-askpass-environment-variable).   Not sure how practical/difficult it would be though.

Comment: I was thinking something similar to what you can do with touch ID, where it is possible to [activate a PAM module to authorise `sudo` with touch ID](https://angristan.xyz/touch-id-sudo-macbook/) on the CLI.

Comment: That would be neat!  A quick look [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/pam_modules/pam_modules-173.50.1/modules/) doesn't show such a module yet unfortunately.

Comment: @Gummibando I second Tonin in this: Transform the comment into an answer, I'll be happy to upvote it (tried it and it worked great)

Comment: @Tonin Converted. Cheers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a PAM module for this on GitHub:

https://github.com/biscuitehh/pam-watchid

(This is forked from a TouchID PAM module, btw.)